# Adding radio button to MySQL fetch result and use result value to fetch another record...?

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I want a first radio button to be checked by default. When I click get schedule I want to fetch the schedule of that radio selected train number using a `WHERE` clause.

```
<?php

while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type = radio />" . $res['Train_no'] . "</td>";

    ?>

    <form action="schedule.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
        <input type="submit" value="Get Schedule"/>
    </form>
<?php

}


<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if ($con) {
    $db = mysql_select_db('traindb', $con);
} else {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


    $selected_val = $_POST['Train_no'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo "You have selected :" . $selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM train_detail WHERE Train_No='$selected_val'");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please correct the code formatting. To get the first radio checked - use a variable like `$firstLoop = true` plus an `if ($firstLoop) {` statement for adding `checked` attribute to the `<input..`. Your radio input should have a `name=` and a `value=` attributes. You should probably read a little about [HTML forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: Use mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: @b2ok ..with mysqli its show error

Comment: @Picard ..thanks picard... how to add name and value and checked attribute to input..here....my echo result not showing selected value....

Comment: Please check the provided link - there you will find this kind of info.

Comment: @PdC hello... can you give me code how to set name, value, and checked attribute to radio button in fetch array result... i did like this   
  echo "<td><input type ="radio" name = "rdbtrain" value = 
                ".$res['Train_no']." /></td>";

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
   $selected_val = $_POST['Train_no'];  // Storing Selected Value In 
   echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM train_detail WHERE 
   Train_No='$selected_val'");
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to set name and value to radio button...my column name is "Train_no"

Comment: @user7808845 Do you want your radio button to be checked?

Comment: i have added radio button to all my fetched records.. i want to select that records value and fetch another record.. first records should be  checked by default...

Comment: help me in echo line

Comment: ..how to add name and value and checked attribute to input..here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of "select":

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select type="age" class="form-control" id="age" name="age">
     <!-- <option value="disable" selected="">Please Select</option> -->
     <option value="">Please select</option>
     <option value="Under 35">Under 35</option>
     <option value=">35 - 44">35 - 44</option>
     <option value=">45 - 54">45 - 54</option>
     <option value=">55 - 59">55 - 59</option>
     <option value=">60 - 64">60 - 64</option>
     <option value=">65 - 69">65 - 69</option>
     <option value=">70 - 74">70 - 74</option>
     <option value=">75 - 79">75 - 79</option>
     <option value="80 +">80 +</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
$age = $_POST['age'];
if (isset($_POST['age']) &&  $_POST['age'] == "")
echo "You did not choose any options. Pls try again.";
else {
echo $age;
}
?>
```

If you want embed PHP in select options, do it like this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $res['Train_no'] ?>"><?php echo $res['some_other'] ?></option>
```

For radio button it is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="<?php echo $res['Train_no'] ?>" checked><?php echo $res['some_other'] ?><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```